# jQuery $.each on Global Array

Tags: jquery

Do you have any idea why this function breaks?

I retrieve the value of a global array using window.
I get the arr object values with console.log
But if I try to use the arr object in the foreach, it breaks the code.
Any ideas why?

```
function setDropDownList(raw_id, val){
    // Get the ID
    var the_id = '#'+raw_id;
    // Get the array name as a string
    var arrname = val+"Array";
    // get the arr object using the arrname string
    var arr = window[arrname];
    // if I place a console.log here, i get the values for the arr object, but it brakes the .each below:

    // do a simple foreach
    // using arr breaks the foreach loop
    // if I use the actual array declared globally in he header it works.
    jQuery.each(arr, function(key, value) {
        var test = value.split('|');
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"?  What happens in the `.each`?  What *does* `console.log(arr)` print?

Comment: Indeed how does it break?

Comment: The console.log(arr) shows the arr object just fine if there is no $.each. When I do the loop, the console.log() for arr shows: undefined

Comment: I love how he took my edit to make it proper english and re-edited it back to be incorrect.

Comment: @user2065483: And what *is* that object, exactly?

Comment: Sorry Christian, I felt I needed to add more explanations, I did not realize you corrected it.

Comment: var myglobalArray = ['1|1','2|2','3|3','4|4','5|5']; The "val" would be "myglobal" and I get a string arrname="myglobalArray". I use arrname to get the actual myglobalArray inside the function using: arr = window[arrname];

Comment: @user2065483: Your code works for me as-is: http://jsfiddle.net/L834Y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because one (or all) of the items in your array is/are not strings.

When you do `value.split('|')`, it requires the value to be a string. Otherwise, it'll break.

Comment: I used numbers for testing only... I never considered that. This is why you have 16.1 k experience

Comment: I'm a mere newbee in the place crowded with real experts. Glad that my answer helped you.

Comment: I have changed the array, still not working... is there another method besides split I could use? If I input the array directly, instead of arr, it works.